# Unable to see coded UI test file in Visual Studio Proffesional 2015

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Please let me know how can I create a Coded UI Test in Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Only unit test file is displayed. Please click on the link below to view the options displayed to me.

[Only unit test file is dispalyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02dxP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Professional version of Visual Studio does not support Coded UI. You need to have the Enterprise version to use Coded UI. Here is a link that describes the difference between the Pro and Enterprise version: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/03/16/6-differences-between-vs-2015-enterprise-and-pro/

Though you are using 2015 version, the 2017 version comparison has the most up to date info, this info can also apply for version 2015 in regards to Coded UI. You can use the info from this link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/